# Use of [windows-live] versus [windows-live-id]

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently [windows-live](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live) seems to be used to refer to Windows Live accounts, which would make it synonymous with [windows-live-id](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live-id).  However, Windows Live is unfortunately a relatively broad set of services and programs, so I'm not entirely sure a synonymization would work.

Should we do anything with these tags?  Perhaps just wait and see how it plays out?

Answer (score 1):

The actual name is Microsoft Account or Windows Live Account, which was a recent from Windows Live ID (and before that, the whole Wallet/Passport series). So, as Windows Live is a whole brand I would leave that tag as-is, where-as I would suggest renaming [windows-live-id](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live-id) to [windows-live-account](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live-account) as long as that is what http://account.live.com has to say.

Alternatively, one might find the tags to become somewhat repetitive / long, so one could also consider:

- [live](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live) for questions about Windows Live services, if any.
- [live-mail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-mail) for Windows Live Mail questions, often used in conjunction with [messaging](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messaging).
- [live-account](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-account) for questions regarding Windows Live accounts.

What do others think?

Comment: While the offical name for it may be "Windows Live Account", most places within the Microsoft universe refer to it as the Windows Live ID, take a look at the [live.com](http://www.live.com) website. First text box is "Windows Live ID". I'm not disagreeing, but what are people more likely to refer to it as?

Comment: @vcsjones: There is a huge difference between ID and Account, ID is the identification that gives you access to your Account. When logged in, I see Account; the only place I see ID is when logging in. I would suppose people to use a word instead of an acronym; Microsoft's want it to be Account, Wikipedia refers to it as an Account (telling us it was known as ID) so I guess we better represent what they want it to be than what it has been. But well, that's just an opinion; I just enumerated some possibilities but am not clear myself what road we could take...